# Can't write Greek RecipeName in xcookybooky

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, input-encodings, greek, xcookybooky

I am using `xcookybooky` to create my own cookbook in greek. Until now I was using `iso-8859-7` encoding in all my documents and it was working fine. With `xcookybooky` there is an issue with this particular encoding. All the letters appear like "Chinese" and the weird thing is that there are no errors.

I tried to change the encoding to `utf8` and something rather strange happened. All greek letters appeared as they should be, exept from the RecipeName. There are also some errors that have to do with greek letters and T1.

My code is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}

\usepackage{tikz} % for creating the lines for the hint
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % To wrap the tabular with the ingredients
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{lettrine} % numbering the preparation steps
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{tabularx} % line breaks in tabular
\usepackage{xcookybooky}

\begin{document}
\begin{recipe}{Μπανάνα}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ingredients{
2 αυγά\\
3 & μπανάνες\\
\unit[200]{ml} & βούτυρο\\
\unit[40]{g} & ζάχαρη\\
\unit[50]{g} & κακάο
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\preparation{
\step Πρώτο βήμα
\step Δεύτερο Βήμα
\step Τρίτο Βήμα
\step Τέταρτο Βήμα
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\setRecipenameFont{cmr}{T1}{m}{n}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setHeadlines{
inghead = Υλικά,
prephead = Προετοιμασία,
hinthead = Μυστικό,
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

My outputs are

**utf8 encoding**

[image]

**iso-8859-7 encoding**

[image]

Any ideas on that? Note that I'm using `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to achieve greek hand-written fonts in the title. Unfortunately I cannot avoid `XeLaTeX`, so I am just changing locally the font style, in the `RecipeName` entry while having set a main font for the entire document(`kerkis`, that is). The code is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Kerkis}
\newfontfamily\kiki{Aka-AcidGR-Kiki}

\usepackage{tikz} % for creating the lines for the hint
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % To wrap the tabular with the ingredients
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{lettrine} % numbering the preparation steps
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{tabularx} % line breaks in tabular
\usepackage{xcookybooky}

%\setRecipenameFont{fau}{T1}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\begin{recipe}{\kiki  \Huge Μπανάνα}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ingredients{
2 αυγά\\
3 & μπανάνες\\
\unit[200]{ml} & βούτυρο\\
\unit[40]{g} & ζάχαρη\\
\unit[50]{g} & κακάο
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\preparation{
\step Πρώτο βήμα
\step Δεύτερο Βήμα
\step Τρίτο Βήμα
\step Τέταρτο Βήμα
}
\setHeadlines{
inghead = Υλικά,
prephead = Προετοιμασία,
hinthead = Μυστικό,
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setRecipenameFont{fau}{T1}{m}{n}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

and the ouput is

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You have to tell `xcookybooky` what's the font you want to use for the recipe title, using the correct parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}

\usepackage{tikz} % for creating the lines for the hint
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % To wrap the tabular with the ingredients
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{lettrine} % numbering the preparation steps
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{tabularx} % line breaks in tabular
\usepackage{xcookybooky}

\setRecipenameFont{mak}{\encodingdefault}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
\begin{recipe}{Μπανάνα}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ingredients{
2 αυγά\\
3 & μπανάνες\\
\unit[200]{ml} & βούτυρο\\
\unit[40]{g} & ζάχαρη\\
\unit[50]{g} & κακάο
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\preparation{
\step Πρώτο βήμα
\step Δεύτερο Βήμα
\step Τρίτο Βήμα
\step Τέταρτο Βήμα
}
\setHeadlines{
inghead = Υλικά,
prephead = Προετοιμασία,
hinthead = Μυστικό,
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You code is working!!! However, I cannot use handwritten fonts for the recipe name. I tried `\setRecipenameFont{fau}{\encodingdefault}{m}{n}` but the output is http://i.imgur.com/6sSMeBJ.png

Comment: There is no `fau` font family that I know of, at least in TeX Live

Comment: No? I found it on the `xcookybooky`'s manual. http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcookybooky/xcookybooky.pdf on page 7 and this is actualy working. I've tested it in English and all of the suggested fonts are working.

Comment: @Thanos It's quite probable that the font doesn't have support for Greek.

Comment: In that case what and how can I modify in order to use greek handwritten font in the recipename?

Comment: @Thanos Do you know of any handwritten Greek font? I don't. And I'm not looking for them either, sorry.

Comment: In fact I know a few, but I don't know hot to make them work just for the recipename, and not for the entire document.

Comment: @Thanos If they are already setup for LaTeX with the LGR encoding support, then just passing the family name instead of `mak` (for Kerkis) should be sufficient. If they are not already set up for LaTeX, then the work you have to do is quite big.

Answer (score 3):

Use `xelatex`, it makes live easier ... The following was tested with up-to-date MikTeX under Win7. Choose another script font if you do not have `segoesc.ttf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\newfontface\rnFont[Scale=3]{segoesc.ttf}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{xcookybooky}
\makeatletter
\let\xcb@font@recipename\rnFont
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{An example}
\begin{recipe}{Μπανάνα}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ingredients{
2 αυγά\\
3 & μπανάνες\\
\unit[200]{ml} & βούτυρο\\
\unit[40]{g} & ζάχαρη\\
\unit[50]{g} & κακάο
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\preparation{
\step Πρώτο βήμα
\step Δεύτερο Βήμα
\step Τρίτο Βήμα
\step Τέταρτο Βήμα
}
\setHeadlines{
inghead = Υλικά,
prephead = Προετοιμασία,
hinthead = Μυστικό,
}
\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! When I first started LaTeX, I wasn't able to work well with `xelatex`;I was using TXC that didn't `xelatex` compilation. Anyway, I tried your code but I get something weird. http://i.imgur.com/jHY3zcz.png How about the RecipeName? It's missing from your picture...

Comment: the problem with TXC is that old versions didn't support UTF8 which is the default for `xelatex` and `lualatex`. The latest version of TYC supports UTF8. And, of corse, you have to configure TXC to save the files in utf8.

Comment: Indeed I use the TXC 2.0 beta and my document is saved as `utf8`. One more thing. Did your code produce a recipename as a heading? Because with `utf8` that's my main problem...

Comment: see my edited answer, it has now my complete code.

Comment: Still it's not working. http://i.imgur.com/aEyqUyg.png I get the example in "greeklish" but not what's inside the `recipe` environment.

Comment: that looks like a problem with the font. Can you provide the log file?

Comment: You can find it here http://pastebin.com/HUChgpXu Note that I don't use your suggested font because I don't have it installed on my system.

Comment: you didn't run my example! Do not load the `kerkis` package after `fontspec`

Comment: Your exact code produces this http://pastebin.com/Et6vjLp0 and the output is http://i.imgur.com/oaF2Qwt.png with 186 errors. If I remove the djvu font the log is http://pastebin.com/0GziqD08 and the output is http://i.imgur.com/C81Lqmv.png with no errors at all.

Comment: I'll try it on MikTeX later. I always use Linux and TeXLive

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: Wow! You got it all working without using `XeLaTeX`. That's cool! Thank's!!!

Comment: Actualy there is something wrong... Somehow the command `\newfontface\rnFont[Scale=3]{segoesc.ttf}` cannnot be recognised... My output is http://i.imgur.com/bA0er2o.png

Comment: you have to run `xelatex` and _not_ `pdflatex`

Comment: I used `XeLaTeX` but the output is really weird. http://i.imgur.com/rnZrtn9.png

Comment: what TeX distribution do you have installed? I have TeXLive 2013

Comment: It's `MikTex 2.9`

Comment: looks like a problem with MikTeX. I am no MikTeX user so I cannot help here

Comment: ΟΚ! Thank you very much for your help and time!!!